# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'tblOpenAct'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Why I am getting error

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'tblOpenAct'"

in below code:

```
private BMS2Entities _db = new BMS2Entities ();

public tblOpenAct getActTypes()
{
    return (_db.tblOpenActs.Select(a => a.actType)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Your query is returning a `string` (because of your `.Select(a => a.actType)` statement and `actType` is `string`). If you want to return a `tblOpenAct` then remove the `.Select(...)` Or if you just want to return the value of `actType`, change the signature to `public string getActTypes()`

Comment: what if I want to use select then what shuld be the method return type

Comment: See the 2nd part of the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private BMS2Entities _db = new BMS2Entities ();

public string getActTypes()
{
    return (_db.tblOpenActs.Select(a => a.actType)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```